# Number of DNA in a chromosome

Tags: dna

I wanted to know the number of DNA in a chromosome.

I previously knew that there are 2 DNAs per chromosome, but later I think I saw somewhere that it was trying to imply that the number of DNA is one per chromosome.

Please clarify this

Comment: There are two DNA chains per chromosome. There is one unbroken strand of double-stranded DNA per chromosome (except during DNA replication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one or two chromatids per chromosomes (depending upon the stage of the cell cycle) and there are two (anti-parallel) strands of DNA in each chromatid.

As discussed in your previous post, you are using the term DNA incorrectly which makes your questions hard to understand. You should probably just have a look at an intro course to genetics.

If you want to learn through SE posts that I highly recommend you having a look at the posts:

- [Chromosome and chromatid numbers during cell cycle phases](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29656/chromosome-and-chromatid-numbers-during-cell-cycle-phases)
- [How is the diploid chromosome number maintained at mitosis?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44464/how-is-the-diploid-chromosome-number-maintained-at-mitosis)
- [What are homologous chromosomes?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59287/what-are-homologous-chromosomes)
- [Interpretation of picture of human chromosomes](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58449/interpretation-of-picture-of-human-chromosomes)
- [What is the relationship between DNA molecules and the chromosomes?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/63909/what-is-the-relationship-between-dna-molecules-and-the-chromosomes/63916#63916)

Comment: Remi b, could you please suggest edits so that the question renders authentic

Comment: What do you mean by authentic. Authentic means "of undisputed origin". Editing it necessarily reduce its authenticity. Do you mean "more clear"? Just adding "molecule" after the term "DNA" would already much improve the question!